# JSON data is not getting updated through put request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to update the `put` request through REST API, but when I trigger my function, the `put` request is failing to update the information and shows `userdata` is `undefined`.

Actually I am not getting how to define that variable and pass it.

AngularJS:

```
$scope.toggle_save = function(information) {
    $scope.toggle_edit();
    var userdata = information; 
    $http.put('http://localhost:3000/contacts/'+userdata.id, userdata).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        $scope.toggle_edit();
    }, function(data) {
        console.log("Error:" + data)
    });
};
```

`information` is the method which is taken from the `get` request and assigning to `userdata`. After that I am not getting how to pass it.

Any information, any changes?

Comment: which variable is undefined?

Comment: userdata @PrashanthBenny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
  $scope.toggle_save = function(information){
            $http({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/contacts/'+information.id,
                method: 'PUT',
                data: information
            })
            .then(
                function successCallback(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    response = {success: true, data: result};
                    callback(response);
                }, 
                function errorCallback(result) {  
                    console.log(result);  
                    response = {success: false, data: result};
                    callback(response);
                }
            );
 });
```

Comment: But when i run this code, i am getting **userdata** is undefined

Comment: @SRK you need to assign the data to `userdata` i.e. the `information`.. or else you can pass `information` directly instead of  `userdata`

Comment: again i got the same old error. I guess , I need to assign the **information** to one variable and pass it. But i don't know , how to do it

Comment: Then this `information` contains no data.. console and check whether `information` has anything or not

Comment: Just now i checked out. Information contains get data.

Comment: **$scope.cts.information = response.data.contacts;** This is my get request data

Comment: it contains json data. You can check that out

Comment: response data from **get request**

Comment: Here, `$scope.cts.information` will contain array of objects.. can you send what you are passing to the `$scope.toggle_save()` i.e. what you contain in `information` param

Comment: @RNS . I am new to angular js . I am learning learn it. If you know any blog or video tutorial.could you suggest me

Comment: Thank you.Could you provide your blog link. Because, I am getting no.of person in your name

Comment: Check out scotch.io.